# How to Display PHP/SQL List (the entire list)

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm current browsing the website below

http://www.prc.gov.ph/licensure/?id=27

To display the list, select (any) Exam Name and Exam Date then Press Seach.

If the list is very long, it will generate Page numbers at the bottom of the page.

Is it possible if anyone can teach me how to display the entire list so that I can **copy and paste it in Excel**?

[image]

I am trying to get the entire list and that's it. Please help

Comment: not really sure if this is a programming question.

Comment: Is this your site? Or are you asking us how to generate such a list on a 3rd party site?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel In my opinion, he wants to get the entire list which is (probably) located in a database. I think those names are in the database and she wants to scrape it. I think.

Comment: @BenMichaelOracion He or she? :-P I think this is a site by someone else and the OP wants it scraped, they doesn't have direct access to the database at all.

Comment: It's a .GOV website. Don't state the obvious @Marcel Korpel lol

Answer (score 2):

The page above use Ajax call to fetch data, and it function paging with a limit of 20. It do not have view all. So you can not display the entire list.

Comment: is there a possibility to get those data? is it in a database?

Comment: @KareenLagasca The data probably is in a database, but if you don't have direct access to it, then you're lost. The only option is to program a screen scraper that delivers the data in a suitable format.